# How to remove a decimal point in a XSL template

Tags: xml, xslt

I want my value to be 5050, Instead of $50.50 in xsl template. The values are fetching from subTotal[@formattedValue]". please help me to get the value withou decimal point in xsl

Comment: You really need to give more detail here. Could your post a sample of your input XML, the XSLT you are current using, and your expected output? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here are examples using either `translate()` or `replace()`

**XSLT 1.0/2.0**

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(/subTotal/@formattedValue,'$.','')"/>
```

**XSLT 2.0 only**

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(/subTotal/@formattedValue,'[^\d]','')"/>
```

Either one of these applied to:

```
<subTotal formattedValue="$50.50"/>
```

produces:

```
5050
```

Comment: I have an attribute which has the value as below , I need to extract the value 36.26 from the below attribute and convert it into Pence , which means I need to get 3626 as the value. 


<subTotal value="36.2600" formattedValue="£36.26" displayFormat="c">

I need the output as 3626

The below works in XSLT 2.0 version but not in XSLt 1.0
<xsl:value-of select="translate(/subTotal/@formattedValue,'$.','')"/>

Please help me to get this done in all version and also provide anyother alternative ways to fix this issue

Comment: @user1131825 - Just add "£" to the list of characters that need to be translated: `translate(/subTotal/@formattedValue,'$.£','')` This will work in either 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
          var optimizely = optimizely || [];
          optimizely.push(['trackEvent', 'Order Complete', <xsl:value-of select ="uiObjects/order/orderSummary/basketSummary/subTotal/@value"/>]);
                 </script>