# To remove decimal point in all XSLT versions

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove a decimal point in a XSL template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740683/how-to-remove-a-decimal-point-in-a-xsl-template)

I have an attribute which has the value as below , I need to extract the value 36.26 from the below attribute and convert it into Pence , which means I need to get 3626 as the value.

```
<subTotal value="36.2600" formattedValue="£36.26" displayFormat="c">
```

I need the output as 3626

The below works in XSLT 2.0 version but not in XSLt 1.0

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(/subTotal/@formattedValue,'$.','')"/>
```

Please help me to get this done in all version and also provide anyother alternative ways to fix this issue

Comment: Why does the 2nd argument to `translate()` have `$` instead of `£`?

Comment: Also, when you say something doesn't work (in this case, in XSLT 1.0), always tell what it does (and how that differs from the desired output, if not obvious). Would you bring your car to a mechanic and just say "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @LarsH - The OP had `$` in the translate because the original question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740683/how-to-remove-a-decimal-point-in-a-xsl-template/8746404#comment11036586_8746404

Answer (score 2):

£1 = 100 pence

```
<xsl:value-of select="/subTotal/@value * 100"/>
```

If you have to extract value from `@formattedValue` you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(/subTotal/@formattedValue, 2) * 100"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(/subTotal/@formattedValue,'£.','')"/>
```

Comment: That will substitute spaces for `$` and `.`, right?

Comment: yea just noticed also that the poser had $ instead of £ corrected :)

Comment: OK, but my point was about the spaces. The result will be `" 36 26"` instead of `"3626"`.

Comment: your right dude updated it to remove the spaces!