# How to remove a Pound sign from the XML attritbute in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I wanted to remove the Pound Sign(£) in formattedValue attribute in XSLT. Could you please help on that?

```
    <price value="£99.99" formattedValue="£99.99">55.55</price>
```

I need the output as
99.99

Basically, need to remove the Pound sign in XSLT

Comment: possible duplicate of [To remove decimal point in all XSLT versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836850/to-remove-decimal-point-in-all-xslt-versions)

Answer (score 2):

Use translate:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="price">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="price/@formattedValue">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '£', '')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use either the `translate()` function**:

```
translate(@formattedValue, '£', '')
```

**or, what I would recommend in this particular case as shorter and probably more efficient -- use the `substring()` function**:

```
substring(@formattedValue, 2)
```